# How to repeat a program that parses new link from the data

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I want to parse a link and extract around 100 links from there and from these 100 links I have to parse the 18th link and repeat this process 7 times until I get a link with a name starting from M that would be my answer. I have written a python program but it seems that something is wrong. I can write the same code 7 times and get the last link but I want to keep the program shorter. so, how can I write a python program that repeats itself 7 times.
MY CODE:-

```
import urllib.request,urllib.parse,urllib.error
import re
url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Prabhasees.html'
count = 0
no_of_time = 0

while no_of_time<8:
    no_of_time = no_of_time+1
    link = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    for links in link:
        links = links.decode().strip()
        links = re.findall('<a href="(http://.+?)"',links)
        if links == []:continue
        for i in links:
            count += 1
            if count ==18:
               url = i
               print(url)
```

I kept the line "link = urllib.request.urlopen"(just below the while loop) opuside of the loop but it didnt work as well

Answer (score 0):

**Be careful with indentation**

your while loop is not indented properly.

```
while no_of_time<8:
    no_of_time = no_of_time+1
    link = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    for links in link:
        links = links.decode().strip()
        links = re.findall('<a href="(http://.+?)"',links)
        if links == []:continue
        for i in links:
            count += 1
            if count ==18:
                url = i
                print(url)
```

Comment: oh sorry, I just copied the code from my text editor and didn't notice the intendation. Thx by the way

Comment: No problem, please upvote if I helped you :)